# как настроить script yastatic.net для того чтобы постить по кнопке статью в группу OK.ru?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

как настроить script yastatic.net для того чтобы постить по кнопке статью в группу OK.ru? При нажатие например на кнопку VK или F в сплывающем окне есть для них выбор сообщества или группы.